# Searching with Sunspot returns all results in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Inside StreamPage i have defined this code for searching

```
searchable do
    text :html, :stored => true, :boost => 2
    integer :stream_id
end
```

I have 44 record and used reindex on this setting

```
s = StreamPage.search do |st|
    st.keywords 'fsdgsfdgdffsdfgsfdgfd'
end
```

So even when i run above code i get all records, anything i write into keyword i get the result.

Comment: Sunspot logs all queries on sunspot-solr-XXX.log. Please post what query is sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Something is probably off with your search statement. Have you tried using this syntax?

```
s = StreamPage.search { keywords('fsdgsfdgdffsdfgsfdgfd') }
```

My guess is that the use of the `st` local variable is messing things up. I would also verify that everything has been properly indexed by running this command:

```
bin/rake sunspot:reindex
```

Comment: I have tried both way.  Strangest thing is that on model Stream i get right info and it is the same searchable definition only other field is defined.

Comment: Are you sure that the StreamPage#html function is returning the correct text to be indexed?

Comment: Yes. It does. I have found the problem, using word stemming in configuration makes wrong highlighting